# How to get the path of user's special folder in macOS?

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos

Is there any API to get the  user's special folder, such as the Downloads or Documents folder in macOS?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsfilemanager/1407693-urlfordirectory?language=objc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per my exprience I am generally use to get Home directory path as per below example.

**1st Way :**

```
NSArray * paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDesktopDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString * desktopPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

***For Desktop :*** `NSDesktopDirectory`

***For Document :*** `NSDocumentDirectory`

***For Downloads :*** `NSDownloadsDirectory`

**2nd Way:**

> Not the best way but we can get path by this method also.
>
> Use Localization for different languages.

**$Home Directory of Current User:**

```
[NSURL fileURLWithPath:NSHomeDirectory()];
```

**$Home/Desktop**

```
[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Desktop"]];
```

**$Home/Documents :**

```
[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"]];
```

**$Home/Downloads :**

```
[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Downloads"]];
```

Hope this will help you to find special folder path.

Comment: Using NSFileManager defaultManager is better for finding Desktop, Documents, etc. No need to append string components.

Comment: ... and it works whether app is sandboxed or not, returning the appropriate path for the respective configuration.

Comment: "stringByAppending" is not guaranteed to work. An italian user may not have a folder named Desktop, and for any user, these folders may change their location in future OS versions.

Comment: I don't recommend using strings but for clarity the folder names are not localised that way. An Italian or any other localised user will also have the same folder names, it just shows up with a different name in Finder.

Comment: Thanks . Its help me to get proper path. Working as expected

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned by others, a more modern approach is to retrieve a `URL` by using `NSFileManager`:

```
NSURL *desktopUrl = [NSFileManager.defaultManager URLsForDirectory:NSDesktopDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask].firstObject;
```

Answer (score 0):

desktop for Swift 5.x:

```
var DesktopDir : String = {
    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.desktopDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
    return paths[0]
}()
```